# FQL query to fetch all feed posted to my page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I am managing this Facebook Page.
http://www.facebook.com/Ippintestpage

I want to fetch all feeds by fql shown in Facebook page as 'Recent Posts by Others on Ippintestpage'.

I tried to this query on Graph API Explorer,

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 200034893468318
```

but got fewer results than I expected.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": "Facebookページへの投稿テスト"
    }, 
    {
      "message": "testtesttest"
    }, 
    {
      "message": "テスト"
    }, 
    {
      "message": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Is fql query incorrect?
How can I fetch all feeds on Facebook page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with the feed from a page, you should never expect to get all the posts.

Some users block all app access under their privacy settings. You'll see these in the Facebook web app, but they will never be returned by the Graph API or FQL.

If you're authenticating as an app, you also won't see any posts that have their privacy set to something other than "everyone".

Comment: I know the privacy setting is important. But all the posts are public. Is there another reason?

Comment: If the user has **Settings->Apps->Use Apps** set to **Off** you can see their posts from within Facebook, but they will never be returned by the API.

Comment: Thanks.
but the flag "Use apps, plugins, games and websites on Facebook and elsewhere?" of my account is set to on,
and my feeds are not returned by FQL.

Comment: When I run your query, I get 7, the same number I see on your page. http://pastebin.com/ECN9GuUX

Comment: It goes well after getting permission to 'read_stream'. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> SELECT message FROM stream WHERE actor_id != 200034893468318 AND source_id = 200034893468318